# Understanding Django and Django FormView

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a Django web app that accepts text in a form/textbox, processes it and redirects to a webpage showing the processed text . I have written a half-functioning app and find de-bugging quite challenging because I don't understand most of what I've done. I'm hoping you will help me understand a few concepts, Linking to resources, also appreciated.

1. Consider this simple model:

   ```
   class ThanksModel(models.Model):
        thanks_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   ```

   Is the only way to set the text of thanks_text through the manage.py shell? This feels like a pain if I just have one piece of text that I want to display. If I want to display a webpage that just says 'hi', do I still need to create a model?
2. Consider the view  and template below:

   ```
   views.py
   class TestView(generic.FormView):
     template_name = 'vader/test.html'
     form_class = TestForm
     success_url = '/thanks/'

   test.html
   <form action = "{% url 'vader:thanks'%}" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }} 
     <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
   </form>
   ```

   I need to create another model, view and html template and update urls.py for '/thanks/' in order for the success_url to redirect correctly? (That's what I've done.) Do I need to use reverse() or reverse_lazy() the success_url in this situation?

Comment: 1. No, and no. If you just want to put some static text on a page, why do you need a model at all? And if you do want something that can be modified, of course you can do it online through the admin or via a form you created, not just via the shell. 2. No, you don't need a model for a thanks page, but of course you do need a view and template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models are used when you are dealing with Objects and Data and DataBases that can contain a lot of information. 
For Example A Person would be a model. their attributes would be age, name, nationality etc.

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Thi deals with multiple bits of information for one object. (the object being the person)

A Thank you message would not need this? so scrap the model for the thank you message. just have views where you create the view using a templates and setting the view to a url.

---

**views.py**

```
class TestView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'vader/test.html'  # self explantory
    form_class = TestForm  # grabs the test form object
    success_url = reverse_lazy('vader:thanks') # this makes sure you can use the name of the url instead of the path

def ThanksView(request):  # its simple so you don't even need a class base view. a function view will do just fine. 
    return render(request,"thanks.html")
```

**test.html**

```
<form action = "{% url 'vader:thanks'%}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }} 
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```

**thanks.html**

```
    <h1>Thank you for Submitting</h1>
    <h2> Come Again </h2>
```

**url.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from djangoapp5 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TestView.as_view(), name='test_form'),
    path('thanks/', views.ThanksView, name='vader:thanks'),

]
```

I haven't tested this but hopefully it helps and guide you in the right direction